# Putting footer bottom of page through 100% height

Tags: css

I am trying to create a footer for my page. I have tried to make it stick at the absolute bottom of the page and after some online research it told me to modify the height value of my body. However, once I do that, nothing changes. Here is my code:

```
    *{
margin:0;
padding:0:
}

html{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
}

/*****************/
/*****HEADER******/
/*****************/



#header{

    width: 100%;

    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:2.5%;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:0px;

    padding-top:2%;
    padding-bottom:0.5%;
    padding-left:0%;
    padding-right:0%;

    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color: black;

    background: lightgrey;
}

#header>h1{
    color:black;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#header>p{
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    color:black;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

/*****************/
/*****Body******/
/*****************/

#content{

    position: relative;

    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}


#content>p{
    margin-left:2.5%;
}

#intro_text{
    font-style: italic;

    margin-bottom:2.5%;
}

#main_nav{
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-left:5%;
}




/*****************/
/******FOOTER*****/
/*****************/

#footer{

    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

    bottom: 0;

}
```

EDIT: Added HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
     <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <h1>My Web Space</h1>
            <p> First HTML Page using Sublime Text</p>
        </div>



        <div id="content">

            <p id=intro_text>Hello, my name is Alex and I am an aspiring web designer</p>


            <p>Links to various test pages I am working with</p>
            <ul id=main_nav>
                <li><a href=test_link.html>Linking to another page test</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p id=footer_text>Me, 2016</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: HTML? and do you actually want the footer visible at all times, or to be on the bottom, after scrolling?

Comment: Updated with HTML. I just want the footer to be at the absolute bottom of the page, but if the content is smaller than the browser, then it goes to the bottom of the browser. Ie. I don't want one that stays at the bottom while you scroll.

Comment: If you use flexboxes you can avoid lots of hassle. https://jsfiddle.net/sabgu8r4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is the core logic of the solution:

```
html{
  position: relative; /* Allows the footer to notice content height */
  min-height: 100vh;  /* My page will always take the full screen */
}

main{
  margin-bottom: 100px; /* prevents footer overlap (footer height + 20px) */
}

footer{
  position: absolute; /* I don't care about other things */
  bottom: 0; /* I want to be on the bottom... */
  left: 0;   /* ...and to the left */
}
```

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/motaha/edit?html,css,output)

I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

---

- This answer does not use **flexbox** its pure ol' css.

Comment: Even though the **flexbox** answer works perfectly, I felt like posting a solution without using it, in case somebody needs it that way.

Comment: Much appreciated, especially useful for a beginner like me who's just trying to understand boxes and everything

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. Take it easy, step by step. But when you get a bit better learn flexbox its brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this just modifying #footer

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0:
}

html{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
}

/*****************/
/*****HEADER******/
/*****************/



#header{

    width: 100%;

    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:2.5%;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:0px;

    padding-top:2%;
    padding-bottom:0.5%;
    padding-left:0%;
    padding-right:0%;

    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color: black;

    background: lightgrey;
}

#header>h1{
    color:black;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#header>p{
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    color:black;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

/*****************/
/*****Body******/
/*****************/

#content{

    position: relative;

    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}


#content>p{
    margin-left:2.5%;
}

#intro_text{
    font-style: italic;

    margin-bottom:2.5%;
}

#main_nav{
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-left:5%;
}




/*****************/
/******FOOTER*****/
/*****************/

#footer{

    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  background:#f00;
  width:100%;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
     <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <h1>My Web Space</h1>
            <p> First HTML Page using Sublime Text</p>
        </div>



        <div id="content">

            <p id=intro_text>Hello, my name is Alex and I am an aspiring web designer</p>


            <p>Links to various test pages I am working with</p>
            <ul id=main_nav>
                <li><a href=test_link.html>Linking to another page test</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p id=footer_text>Me, 2016</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: This footer stays on your screen all the time. I thought you just wanted to push it down to the bottom, not get it stuck on the screen. @alexp2603

Answer (score 1):

Using flexboxes, you can extend the content area to fill the wrapper

JSfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/sabgu8r4](https://jsfiddle.net/sabgu8r4/)

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

/*****************/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0:
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/*****************/
/*****HEADER******/
/*****************/

#header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  padding-right: 0%;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  background: lightgrey;
}

#header>h1 {
  color: black;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#header>p {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}


/*****************/
/*****Body******/
/*****************/

#content {
  /*position: relative;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;*/
}

#content>p {
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}

#intro_text {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

#main_nav {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}


/*****************/
/******FOOTER*****/
/*****************/

#footer {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  /*position: relative;
  bottom: 0;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">
    <h1>My Web Space</h1>
    <p> First HTML Page using Sublime Text</p>
  </div>



  <div id="content">

    <p id=intro_text>Hello, my name is Alex and I am an aspiring web designer</p>

    <p>Links to various test pages I am working with</p>

    <ul id=main_nav>
      <li><a href=test_link.html>Linking to another page test</a></li>

    </ul>

    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p id=footer_text>Me, 2016</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually gave exactly what I wanted. Is using flexbox a CSS best practice?

Comment: Flexbox is still not 100% supported, but feel free to use it. You can check [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) why i said it's not 100% supported. I would advise you learn it before you start using it, it's not that simple, yet it can be very very useful.

Comment: It's supported by almost all modern browsers, so don't worry about that. [Here's](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) a good guide about flexboxes.

Comment: Yeah like @poi said its pretty much 100% supported. Oh and here's a good [Playground](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) for flexboxes.

Comment: Thank you guys much appreciated!